# How to make an API call and store the contents?

Tags: asp.net, json, .net

I'm new to ASP.Net and I've done a full course on fundamentals but there is a few things that I'm missing.

The project I'm working on requires me to pull data from an API call which gives me back a response of a JSON file with the data I need. (Sorry I'm unable to provide the link as the data is confidential to the company) but to simulate what I get back

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "companyName": "thenameishere"
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "companyName": "thenameishere"
 },
and so on...
]
```

I'm using HttpClient but I'm unsure on how to write my code for the call at all even after some extensive research I'm unable to understand it.

**I'm ONLY working with GET method... I'm not touching POST or any other.**

If someone can give me some detailed example of how to make a call I can figure out the rest myself and how to use the data and store it.

Comment: This is readily available online. A simple Google search should suffice.

Comment: You say that but I dont know what to ask google as I've tried so many things and its either I don't understand or I'm asking for the wrong thing.

Comment: [Here](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=httpclient+web+api+call+c%23). It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

this is code i am using for get

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var baseAddress = "http://localhost:5000";

    var api = "/api/controller/action/params";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(api);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
    }
}
```

you will have to replace  with the class you are expecting to be returned

Comment: Are you able to explain more on what the code actually does? 
Line by line if possible I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @DaLegacy you have to find a tutorial if you crave to learn HTTP not to use it. I don't care how it works, I need a result.

Comment: Okay no problem, thanks for a possible solution.

Comment: I personally don't think we should encourage this kind of "question" in SO.
That being said, current recommendation is to avoid disposing of the `HttpClient` instance and use it as a Singleton instead.

Comment: @JuanR OP doesn't know how to use this simplified pattern since it looks too complicated to him. I don't see any sense to talk about httpclient factory  or typed http clients.

Comment: @Serge I don't see any sense on answering this question either since this can be easily found/learned online but since you posted an answer, other people will read this and incorrectly use the code so it's not just for the OP's benefit.

Comment: @JuanR Did your read this in  the questio comments: " but I dont know what to ask google as I've tried so many things and its either I don't understand or I'm asking for the wrong thing." How could I pass it? But as I expected  OP doesnt' appreciate it . Answer is not accepted and I have only problems so far.

Comment: @Serge I hear you. That's why I don't answer these questions, LOL...